# RSA_sign(), object(3) and NID_sha1

Tags: c, openssl, manpage

The manpage for [`RSA_sign()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/RSA_sign/) says about the `type` parameter:

> `type` denotes the message digest algorithm that was used to generate `m`.
>          It usually is one of `NID_sha1`, `NID_ripemd160` and `NID_md5`; see
>          *objects(3)* for details.

I included the headers as suggested, but my IDE claims there are no variables starting with `NID_` and I couldn't find the objects manpage anywhere on  the internet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the objects manpage has never been written. [Here's the bug report from whoopin' 2007.](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?user=guest&pass=guest&id=1600)

As [Dan Grossman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280598/dan-grossman) helpfully [pointed out](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/522154#522154), the objects manpage would document  [objects.h](https://projects.commandprompt.com/public/odbcng/browser/ODBCng/openssl/objects.h?rev=1); including either that, or engine.h as the [RSA manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/rsa/rsa-0.9.8i.php) suggests, fixed the problem.

Comment: Morale: don't write new code against the openssl crypto libs.

Comment: For clarity, 
     #include <openssl/objects.h>

Comment: @badp Can you explain what crypto library to use with openssl, if not using openssl crypto library?

Comment: @xuhfev several OpenSSL forks happened as a result of Heartbleed. I haven't had to look into this since the time of asking though